# Slime trap in slime chunk gave TONS of slime once, and then never again

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been reading the questions here but haven't found anyone reporting this situation. I set up a slime trap in a slime chunk, and most nights nothing spawned. One night, in about 30 seconds 8 or 9 slimes spawned and I got a bunch of slime.

The only thing I noticed different about that night was that my computer had the screen saver come on, and when i returned to the game, that was when the slime appeared.

I'm playing a multiplayer game with my family. I was worried they were causing no slime to spawn by having mobs chase them near my slime trap, so they left and went to another part of the world. Reading the mob spawning rates in the dubug screen, it never gets above 50/300 or so if I look up, and it never gets above 6 if I am looking at my slime trap. The only thing I have specifically measured is the cycle of the moon, but its hard to believe it can go from 8 spawning one night to 0 for the next 5 minecraft nights.

[image: View of my slime trap from 24-36 blocks away]

[image: View of my slime trap]

Comment: This can have tons of reasons, is the complete area around you lit up properly? Where do you stand while waiting for mobs to spawn (<24 Blocks away)?
How many people are online at the same time(mob cap)? and many many more

Comment: The most common hard to check reason why mob farms stop working is a big group of mobs hidden somewhere that don't despawn. You could try walking >250 blocks away and then coming back, but not all mobs that can fill the mob cap despawn.

Comment: For one thing, you haven't sufficiently lit the floor of your slime farm. Zombies, creepers, skeletons, spiders and endermen are all capable of spawning in it (and are much more likely to). Of those, only the zombies are likely to get killed by the cactus. Not only that, but the cactus is going to destroy a sizeable portion of all of the drops.